# requests very slow and sometimes return error

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I run requests

```
url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/boston-ma/mip/the-oceanaire-seafood-room-455904020'
r = requests.get(url)
```

but sometimes it takes long time and returns the Response object, and sometimes returns an error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.yellowpages.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /boston-ma/mip/the-oceanaire-seafood-room-455904020 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")))
```

usually, requests is extremely fast, but now, on this webpage and similar from this website, it's unstable. Maybe I need to use another alternative other than requests ? or it's the issue from the webpage ?

Comment: Sounds like you're being rate limited

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a difference it would make, but you could try using a `requests.Session` object.

Comment: can you please help me to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being rate-limited. That means that the server counts how often you request data, and stops responding after you have sent a certain number of requests.

The easiest solution to this is to just wait for a bit and then try again. Normally, this resets after a certain amount of time has passed.

If your script sends multiple requests, try adding a delay between your requests, e.g. with `time.sleep()`:

```py
for _ in range(10):
    requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)  # One second of delay. You may need to increase this.
```

#### Using a Session

If you send multiple requests in a row, you can speed up the requests by utilizing a requests.Session. This makes sure the connection to the server stays open and configured and also persists cookies as a nice benefit. Try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60843169/5712053)):

```py
import requests
session = requests.Session()
url = "..."  # Add your URL here
for _ in range(10):
    session.get(url)
```

#### Didn't solve your problem?

If that did not solve your issue, I have collected some other possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599037/5712053).

Comment: Glad to hear I could solve your issue. Let me know in case you have trouble implementing it.